Open a second popup in a Android WebView
I build a little wrapper Android App around a website that i use very frequently. Essentially, it's a wrapper for the website using a WebView.
The problem is, that my webview doesnt show popup on top on a popup.
https://github.com/wagenknecht/Backloggd-Android-App/issues/1
I dont know why thats the case.
All code is open-source here https://github.com/wagenknecht/Backloggd-Android-App/

Fixed it myself. It was a problem with the DOM.
myWeb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

